# ASP.NET Ajax.BeginForm with angularjs handlers

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

I have a razor partial view which makes use of Ajax.BeginForm. Problem is that I want to handle ajax response via angular controller which is attached to this view. While I can attach custom attributes to inputs using htmlattributes, I couldn't find anything similar for Ajax.BeginForm helper aside from AjaxOptions. But how can I define angular controller method inside it?

upd: I know that OnSuccess etc. ajax events can be handled via regular javascript like below:

```
<div class="content">
        @*@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AccountCheckLogin2", "Login", null, new AjaxOptions { OnFailure = "OnFailure", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", UpdateTargetId = "result" }, new { @name = "form", role = "form" }))*@
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AccountCheckLogin2", "Login", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccessLogin", OnBegin = "OnBeginLogin", OnComplete = "OnCompleteLogin", OnFailure = "OnFailureLogin" }))
        {
            //inputs here
        }
           <a class="link" href="/Registration/Registration">Я не зареестрований</a>
        </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">       
    function OnSuccessLogin(response) {
        if (response.ResponseCode == "1") {
            window.location = "/";
        }
        else
        {                
            $("#LoginValidationSummary ul").append("<li>"+response.ResponseMessage+"</li>");
        }
    }
    function OnBeginLogin() {
        $("#loginSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
    }
    function OnCompleteLogin() {
        $("#loginSubmit").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    function OnFailure() {
        alert("Whoops! That didn't go so well did it?");
    }

</script>
```

question is, can I handle this events via Angular methods?

Comment: you mean by using htmlAttributes?

Comment: if it can be achieved by htmlattributes then yes, but frankly I have no idea what attribute should be applied in order to handle ajax response in angular

Comment: You can set the controller that will be used for the form if that's what you want or you can apply it to any html `<div>`

Comment: I've updated the question with code sample to show what I'm trying to do

Comment: You may not want to use `Ajax.BeginForm` for what you want to do but rather do everything the angular way and define the controller and attach it to the form

Comment: In that case, how can I display validation errors? Currently I have ValidationSummary which carries all possible server errors, but can I make it work with angular or I have to get rid of razor helpers completely?

Answer (score 1):

try this,
JS:

```
var _myCtrlscope;
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
_myCtrlscope = $scope;           
 $scope.foofunction = function (data) {
            // do your stuff with data here.
        }
    });
```

### Razor:

```
Ajax.BeginForm("controllerName", "actionName", 
new AjaxOptions {OnSuccess = "_myCtrlscope.foofunction"}
```

Let me know if it works, thanks!